Los datos no se insertan y no obtengo error al momento de guardar Oracle con OCI8
No se inserta la información requerida si vale la conexión pero no se guarda los datos en la base de datos.
Se prueba y si se guardan los valores a los parámetros.
Se le envía por secciones pero no se guarda.
<?php
    include "coneccion_oracle.php"; 
    
    // Verifica que el método de solicitud sea POST
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Obtiene los datos del formulario
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'] ?? null;
        $apellido = $_POST['apellido'] ?? null;
        $cedula = $_POST['cedula'] ?? null;
        $dinero = $_POST['dinero'] ?? null;
        $tramite = $_POST['tramite'] ?? null;
        $action_type = $_POST['submit'] ?? null; // Captura el valor del botón presionado
    
        // Inicia una transacción
        oci_begin_transaction($conn);
    
        try {
            if ($action_type == 'depositar' || $action_type == 'retirar') {
                // Consulta para ingresar el depósito o retiro
                $sql = "INSERT INTO SINERCOOP.usuario (nombre, apellido, cedula, monto_dinero, tramite) 
                        VALUES (:nombre, :apellido, :cedula, :dinero, :tramite)";
                $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
                oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':nombre', $nombre);
                oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':apellido', $apellido);
                oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':cedula', $cedula);
                oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':dinero', $dinero);
                oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':tramite', $tramite);
    
                if (oci_execute($stmt, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS)) {
                    echo "Operación exitosa";
                } else {
                    $e = oci_error($stmt);
                    echo "ERROR al ejecutar la consulta: " . $e['message'];
                    oci_rollback($conn); // Deshace la transacción en caso de error
                }
            } elseif ($action_type == 'actualizar') {
                // Consulta para actualizar datos basados en cédula
                $sql = "UPDATE SINERCOOP.usuario SET nombre = :nombre, apellido = :apellido, monto_dinero = :dinero, tramite = :tramite 
                        WHERE cedula = :cedula";
                $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
                oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':nombre', $nombre);
                oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':apellido', $apellido);
                oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':dinero', $dinero);
                oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':tramite', $tramite);
                oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':cedula', $cedula);
    
                if (oci_execute($stmt, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS)) {
                    echo "Actualización exitosa";
                } else {
                    $e = oci_error($stmt);
                    echo "ERROR al ejecutar la consulta: " . $e['message'];
                    oci_rollback($conn); // Deshace la transacción en caso de error
                }
            }
    
            // Confirma la transacción
            oci_commit($conn);
    
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Si ocurre un error, deshace la transacción
            oci_rollback($conn);
            echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    
        // Libera el recurso del statement y cierra la conexión
        oci_free_statement($stmt);
        oci_close($conn);
    }
  


Hola Biiron, bienvenido/a a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que sepas como funciona la plataforma y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el mensaje de error? ¿podrías explicar mejor que vendría a ser "Se le envía por secciones pero no se guarda."? Realmente no sé que sería eso.

¿Qué muestra el código en pantalla?

Quita temporalmente las envolturas try - catch a ver si saltan errores. No es la causa del problema, pero si estas usando oci_execute($stmt, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS), entonces no necesitas las instrucciones oci_commit / rollback que están al final. Finalmente, debido a que es muy amplio el alcance del try - catch, va a intentar hacer rollback en la BD por cualquier problema que ocurriese en el código, incluso de algo que no tenga nada que ver con Oracle.

quizá no haga nada porque el $action_type  no cumple gon ninguna condición.  Asegúrate que $action_type tenga el valor correcto. Para mi que no hace nada simplemente porque no entra a ningún bloque de los if. Pon un else por si acaso el $action_type no ew correcto.
